# Centralized logging for simple docker applications

Tags: logging, docker

In our company we have just started using Docker platform to make application deployment as simple as possible. Our applications are mostly small, all but one are running on a single Docker container.

We are looking for a simple centralized logging solution, which would allow us to collect the logs from all the applications and manually review them. Maybe add in some alerts in the future.

Until now we used per application logging into simple text files.

I have tried the ELK stack, but it is obviously meant for statistical log and provides to much trouble for the simple use case.

What would the recomended solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too much trouble in what sense? Difficult to set up? Difficult to get information you're interested in out?

Comment: Difficult to make sense of the information given. We just need a way, to view all the logs fillered by application and severity.

Comment: Are you using the Docker logging drivers to send logs to your ELK setup or something else? If you have time, I'd also recommend reading [this article](https://medium.com/@LifeAndDev/using-the-elk-stack-to-analyze-your-s3-logs-981cb5cc5378#668e), it isn't very long, but gives a pretty good example of what you can do with Kibana and how much effort it is.

Comment: I tried both the log4j and docker drivers and inporting data is not important. Just the kibana and elasticsearch seem an overkill to me.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the hosted services like [Sumo Logic](https://www.sumologic.com/pricing/)?

Comment: [syslog](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#/syslog-options)

Comment: Hosted services are not an option (closed environment). But i might have overlooked good old syslog. Will give it a try tomorrow

Comment: There are many centralized logging systems like ELK, splunk, graylog or system based on hdfs storing data but .. they are too "heavy" for you.
so you dont need any analytical solution that is usually provided by tools above (elasticsearch, kibana like u said).

In that case I would go for simple solution with `log4j` and some data store.

Probably combination `log4j` and `mongo db` or elasticsearch - log with with `NoSQLAppender` or elastic appender.

And searching data with basic mongo client like MongoDB Compass

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, will respond tomorrow when I give them a try.

Comment: @Luka just wondering about this topic. Have you done any research or which solution you tried (or using now)?

Comment: Sorry for late response, this was put on hold due to other problems, but now I think I have my solution. I used Graylog2 with ES for storage and visualization, the interface made much more sense to me. And I coupled this with Logspout to collect the logs. Thanks you all.